# getchar issue when check read char against Enter key

Tags: c, getchar

I have a simple c code as follow:

```
#define RECORDS_PER_PAGE 24

int main(void) {
    int i = 0, n;
    char pause_char;

    printf("Enter a number as the stop point: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while (++i <= n) {
        printf("i is: %d\n", i);
        if (i % RECORDS_PER_PAGE == 0) {
            printf("Press Enter to continue...");
            while((pause_char = getchar()) != '\n');
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I enter 30 as the stop point, I got the following output:

i is: 1
i is: 2
i is: 3
...
i is: 24
Press Enter to continue...i is: 25
...
i is: 30

I expect that the program stop when the if condition satisfies. But it continue without paying attention to getchar. But the strange part is when I enter for example 60 as the stop point it will give the following output:

i is: 1
i is: 2
i is: 3
...
i is: 24
(1) Press Enter to continue...i is: 25
...
i is: 30
...
i is: 46
i is: 47
i is: 48
(2) Press Enter to continue...
i is: 49
...
i is: 59
i is: 60

It will stop at (2) but not (1). I now that maybe something in the buffer cause this problem, but I don't understand why. Is there any explanation for it?

Comment: getchar returns an int not a char

Comment: `scanf("%d", &n);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &n);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you read input you end the input by pressing ENTER, thus giving you your number and `\n`, like `30\n`.

So your `scanf` reads out the number and leaves `\n` in the `stdin` buffer,
then `getchar()` comes along and reads a byte, the `\n`.

Simple but ugly solution, add another `getchar()` to read out the `\n`. (Nicer way is to handle it in your `scanf` read directly.)

Comment: Thanks. I add another getchar() and it solves the problem. But would you explain how to handle it in scanf.